# Assigning sequential IDs to two classes instances

Tags: c#, forms

How do we set sequential IDs to two different class instances? I have two data model classes (ModelFirst and ModelSecond). I need to assign an ID for each instance created through user selection. (I am creating a list of dataModels). If it was just one class, I could have used one static int property to keep track of ID: How do we do it when we have two classes?

```
//if it was just one model, I could have done like this
public class TestModels
    {
        private static int UniqueId = 100;     
        public TestModels()
        {
            UniqueId++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How about making another class specifically to hold the `static` variable which both classes are accessing instead of having their own?

Comment: Oh ya. That was a simple and easy solution :)

Comment: ...and use `Interlocked.Increment` to make it thread-safe as required

Comment: @MickyD, oh you mean "... if required"? My bad, I am not native speaker, but [you are right](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/as+required).

Comment: @Sinatr that's quite ok.  I like that link you found.  Here in Australia we typically here _"...as required"_ in TV commercials for things like headache tablet medications.  I see your link demonstrates that hehe.  Good find!  Wishing you well :)

Answer (score 0):

Offloading the creation of the unique id to another class has already been suggested in the comments. I just want to point out that it's also possible to offload it to a base class, given that the two classes model similar things. We know at least that they both implement an id.

```cs
public class BaseClass
{
    private static int UniqueId = 100;
    public int Id {get; private set;}     
    
    public BaseClass()
    {
        Id = UniqueId++;
    }
}

public class TestModels1 : BaseClass
{
    public TestModels1():base()
    {
    }
}

public class TestModels2 : BaseClass
{
    public TestModels2():base()
    {
    }
}
```

Please note that this is not thread-safe.

Comment: It's probably best practice to use `Interlocked.Increment` here